# Navigating through months with AJAX and Solspace Mini Calendar

Tags: solspace, ajax, calendar

EE 2.7.2
Solspace Calendar 1.8.5

I'm running into troubles getting the calendar to change months.  I'm not well versed in jQuery so I'm using the tutorial [found here](http://allthatbuzz.com/post/20349376310/ajax-jquery-solspace-mini-calendar). The calendar is showing up perfectly on the wrapper template, but when clicking the calendar navigation arrows, nothing happens.  Here are my templates:

**Mini Calendar Template:**

```
    <?php
if (isset ($_POST ['month'])):
    $month = $_POST [ 'month'];
    $year = $_POST ['year'];
else:
    $month = date('m');
    $year = date('Y');
endif;
?>

{exp:calendar:cal
    date_range_start="<?php echo $year; ?>-<?php echo $month; ?>-01"
    date_range_end="<?php echo $year; ?>-<?php echo $month; ?>-last"
}
    {display_each_month}
        <table class="Calendar">
            <thead class="Calendar-header">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1" class="Calendar-nav">
                        <a
                            id="mc_prev_month"
                            class="icon left"
                            href="#" alt="{prev_month format="%m"}" title="{prev_month format="%Y"}">&larr;</a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="Calendar-month" colspan="5">
                        <a href="{path='calendar/month'}/{month format="%Y/%m/%d"}">
                            {date format="%F %Y"}
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1" class="Calendar-nav">
                        <a
                            id="mc_next_month"
                            class="icon right"
                            href="#" alt="{next_month format="%m"}" title="{next_month format="%Y"}">
                            &rarr;
                        </a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="mc_days">
                {display_each_day_of_week}
                    <th class="{if day_of_week_is_weekend}weekend{/if} {if day_of_week_is_current}current{/if}">
                        {day_of_week_one}
                    </th>
                {/display_each_day_of_week}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {display_each_week}
                <tr>
                    {display_each_day}
                    <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Calendar-date
                        {if day_in_current_month == FALSE}Calendar-date--mute{/if}
                        {if day_event_total > 0}Calendar-date--hasEvents{/if}
                        {if count == 7}Calendar-date--selected{/if}
                        {if day_is_today}Calendar-date--today{/if}
                        {if day_is_weekend}Calendar-date--weekend{/if}
                        {if day_is_weekday}Calendar-date--weekday{/if}
                    ">
                         {if day_in_current_month}
                            {if day_event_total}<a href="{path='calendar/day'}/{date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/">{/if}
                                {day}
                            {if day_event_total}</a>{/if}
                        {if:else}
                            <strong class="middot">&middot;</strong>
                        {/if}

                    </td>
                    {/display_each_day}
                </tr>
                {/display_each_week}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {/display_each_month}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

**Wrapper template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="drop2"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var month = "<?php echo $month; ?>";
        var year = "<?php echo $year; ?>";

        render_calendar(month,year);

        function render_calendar(month,year) {
            $.post(
                "[site url removed]/inc/mini-calendar",
                { month : month, year : year},
                function(str) {
                    $('#drop2').html(str).fadeIn();
                }
            );
        }

        $(".Calendar-nav a").click(function() {
            $('.Calendar').fadeOut('fast');
            month = $(this).attr('alt');
            year = $(this).attr('title');
            render_calendar(month, year);
        });

    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

<del>You'll notice I've switched to GET instead of POST because of errors with XID hash (or at least that's what I think is going on).</del>

I think it's something really simple here, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: Did you turn on PHP on your template? Do you see any errors/warnings in your browser template? That can give you a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: Both templateshave PHP on and Input parsing stage. I don't see any errors in my developer tools console. The only error I've seen is when I switch to POST method and I get some super generic EE error: "The action you have requested is invalid." Like I mentioned, I presume it has to do with the missing XID Hash.

Comment: If you turn off secure forms in EE, does ajax work correctly then? If so, you indeed need to provide an XID hash (if "secure forms" is enabled in EE).

Comment: Turning off secure forms does indeed allow the calendar to show without any EE errors.  Still, clicking on the navigation arrows doesn't do anything but put a hashtag in the address bar. Something isn't firing when clicking on the calendar navigation links. Is there any glaring problems in the jQuery I posted? Can you duplicate on your end? I've now switched everything to POST since it no longer throws an error.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors in the web inspector console?

Comment: None. Nothing during load of the calendar and nothing on click.